# How to delete dynamically created textbox in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I  have created the code for adding textbox but I do not know to delete the added textbox.

share me how to remove textbox;

```
counter ++; 
TextBox tb = new TextBox(); 
tb.ID = "TextBox" +counter; 
LiteralControl lineBreak = new LiteralControl(); 
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(tb); PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lineBreak);   
controlIdList.Add(tb.ID); 
ViewState["controlIdList"] = controlIdList;
```

Comment: Would be nice to see some effort.  However, you could also disable or hide the textbox.

Comment: '  counter ++;
            TextBox tb = new TextBox();
            tb.ID = "TextBox" +counter;
            LiteralControl lineBreak = new LiteralControl();
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(tb);
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lineBreak);
            controlIdList.Add(tb.ID);
            ViewState["controlIdList"] = controlIdList;'

Comment: Hi, How to remove textbox kindly reply to me...

Comment: @Elavarasan That is better if you write code sample and description rather put link to other site (such as youtube). Your way to ask a question not custom and not useful in stack-exchange sites. Edit your question and i will answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove textbox from your placeholder like below:

```
    protected void Remove(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control control in PlaceHolder1.Controls)
        {
            //Here you need to take ID from ViewState["controlIdList"]
            if (control.ID == "TakeIDFromControlListsID")
            {
                Controls.Remove(control);
            }
        }
     }
```